# In Docker (compose), how to detect when all Flask apps have finished starting up?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a docker-compose project which starts several Flask servers, each in their own container. With one Flask app it is easy to see when it has started up and you can start sending requests since it will print the following:

```
tika-container |  * Serving Flask app "tika_app" (lazy loading)
tika-container |  * Environment: production
tika-container |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
tika-container |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
tika-container |  * Debug mode: off
tika-container |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But when you have 5+ apps starting up, the lines will mix and it becomes very hard to detect whether they are all online.

What is the best way to print a message when all Flask servers have finished starting up?

So far I've thought of creating a script keeps pinging each server until all of them respond and then prints a message but I am wondering if there is a better method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to see if a server runs? If you're simply interested in the output of each image then consider using https://github.com/jesseduffield/lazydocker

Comment: that also https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: @Zun I just want to see when I can start sending requests to the app. I now frequently send requests before all the servers are finished starting up. to avoid this I wait an extra long time but this is wasted time. If I could just see a single line of "All flask apps are running" I would know when I can start sending requests.

Comment: FWIW the prepackaged solutions to a couple of related problems (the `wait-for-it.sh` script to check if your database is actually responding; Kubernetes readiness probes) work by sending requests to the service in question, so I think the script you propose is likely the best solution.  Docker Compose on its own can't distinguish "started the container" from "actively serving requests".

Comment: Then I'll stick to my pinging solution, thanks.

Comment: Is this for local development or is this for a swarm deploy?

Comment: Just local development.